# jQuery Fullcalendar event title click

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to create a title with a delete button and it works well for me. How would I differentiate the event click? Meaning the user clicks on the delete button or the user click on the event itself?

Comment: How do you "click on the event itself"?

Comment: I mean I need to be able to take 2 actions. One is to click on the delete button located in the title of the event and the load the popup when the event itself is clicked. THe event click is working fine, I just can not figure out how to do the title click

Answer (score 1):

One option would be, add a unique class to the delete button, and use fullCalendar's [eventClick()](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) function. It has second parameter `jsEvent` which holds the native javascript event. Using this `jsEvent` you could check the target class , say you've added `delete_btn` as the class of delete button, then do:

```
..
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var $element = $(jsEvent.target);
    if( $element.hasClass("delete_btn") ) {
        //you clicked delete button
    }
    else {
        //you clicked elsewhere in the event block
    }
},
..
```

Note that this is not tested.

Comment: use above solution or use `jsEvent.target.className == "delete_btn"` tested and it works.

Comment: @Franky true, it could be used directly instead of wrapping the target as jQuery object..